# Really easy mySQL

Tags: mysql

I dont know how I don't know this but I don't,

If I have:

```
SELECT value1 + value2 as total from myTable;
```

And I wanted to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable IF(value1 + value2 == 10);
```

What the exact syntax for this?

TIA

Comment: ??? Not sure where that comment came from.  There's nothing wrong with a simple question, no need to get excited. The OP was probably just struggling with MySQL's oh-so-informative `you have an error in your sql syntax` message.

Comment: It was just a brain malfunction, I've done SQL to a intermediate level, but it all just escaped me there for a minute!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE value1 + value2 = 10`